Cannot make the PS5 controller vibrate continuously non-stop wirelessly
I need my PS5 controller to vibrate continuously, non-stop, and really hard. I also need it to do so wirelessly and while not attached to any cords or cables. I have searched the web long and hard and have found no results and no answers—nothing.
How do I make it so that the PS5 controller will vibrate continuously, non-stop, wirelessly, without using USB or auxiliary? Is there a way to force input wirelessly on the controller for this to happen? Thus far, I've tried using my Android smartphone, and it hasn't worked. I haven't yet seen or know of anything available on the PlayStation 5 console itself that's able to accomplish this.
also I need to add that I don't have access to Microsoft Windows operating system whatsoever. I need to be able to do this off of a smartphone off of the PS5 consulate self or off of linux. preferably answers to all three platforms would be great. I hope this is not unreasonable. let me know if there are any non Microsoft Windows options available.
What do I do to rectify and solve this issue?

Welcome! What are you trying to achive?

Welcome Hida!
I don't own a PS5 controller but I found this app that's worth giving a try. It's called Gamepad Massager. It seems that this is only available for Windows so you can try that if you have access to a Windows computer (and since you wanted it to be wireless you would want Bluetooth support).
Another option is that it seems Cyberpunk 2077 has the "Sir John Phallustiff" weapon. It does take some playing time but it seems the weapon triggers vibration on the controller. I don't know much about Cyberpunk 2077 I found this article. The weapon however is NSFW so I wouldn't recommend this route.

yeah I know I opened up the app and it doesn't seem to work at all for the PS5 controller. even on my Microsoft Windows with it paired by bluetooth. what do I do?

the app doesn't seem to work whatsoever for PS5 controller connected by bluetooth but I also doubt that it will work for the PS5 controller connected by cord also. is there a different app that I can use such that it will work with PS5 controller connected by bluetooth?
